# PHP+mysql : What would be the simplest way to calculate individual profits from a transaction list containing deposits, gains and withdrawals

Tags: php, mysql, calculator, bitcoin, accounting

I'm absolutely stumped on the right way to do this (let alone the best way).

I have a group of users with shared quantities of bitcoins. We collectively trade and share the profits each day (minus a small percentage which goes to me for the management).

I'm trying to build a system to accurately calculate profits and fees but I just can't figure out the way to do it.

These are the tables I've created in the mysql db:

tansactions: (this information is pulled from the exchange api)

- id (primary key)
- transactionID (unique)
- transactionType (Deposit, Profit/Loss, Withdrawal)
- amount (btc amount of deposit, profit or loss, withdrawal)
- balance (balance after transaction)
- timestamp (timestamp of the transaction)

users:

- id (primary key)
- nickname (person's name)

accounting:

- id (primary key)
- userId (id from users table)
- transactionType (Deposit, Profit/Loss, Withdrawal)
- amount (btc amount of deposits, calculated profits, withdrawal)
- date

In my mind, I was thinking I would run a nightly script that would calculate the percentage of each person's profits and record it to the accounting table for that day.

I was thinking the accounting table could look something like this with the nightly script:

```
Date        Transaction Amount          Person / System
1/02/2021   Deposit     0.10000000      Person 1
2/02/2021   Profit      0.00041235      System
3/02/2021   Profit      0.00032456      System
4/02/2021   Profit      0.00021435      System
5/02/2021   Deposit     0.13234000      Person 2
6/02/2021   Profit      0.00152390      System
7/02/2021   Profit      0.00143540      System
8/02/2021   Profit      0.00325476      System
9/02/2021   Profit      0.00462534      System
10/02/2021  Deposit     0.00432100      Person 2
11/02/2021  Deposit     0.00625300      Person 3
12/02/2021  Profit      0.00876000      System
13/02/2021  Profit      0.00453720      System
14/02/2021  Profit      0.00642620      System
15/02/2021  Profit      0.00754000      System
16/02/2021  Withdraw    0.00087640      Person 1
17/02/2021  Profit      0.00245300      System
18/02/2021  Withdraw    0.00032625      Person 2
19/02/2021  Profit      0.00134432      System
20/02/2021  Deposit     0.01234500      Person 3
```

I can't think of an easy way to calculate the profit daily...

Any guidance / advice / help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Figured this out..

In short, here are the loops (not the most efficient way but, it works)

```
foreach(user)
{
   check initial deposit amount and date
   make an array of every date since
   foreach(date since)
   {

      check what the whole account did on that day
      calculate this user's percentage on that day
      
      if there is a withdraw / deposit, handle that too
      
   }


}
```

vague but hopefully explains the logic.